# WebStorm to import from index file when using SystemJS module system

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, systemjs

Suppose I have the following source structure.

```
/home
  home.component.ts
/shared
  /domain
    car.domain.ts
    house.domain.ts
    person.domain.ts
    index.ts
```

All the domain files contains something like

```
export interface Car {
  someProperty: number;
}
```

The index file looks like this

```
export * from './car.domain';
export * from './house.domain';
export * from './person.domain';
```

Then in works perfectly fine to import like this in my home component.

```
import { Car, Person } from '../shared/domain';
```

or

```
import { Car, Person } from '../shared/domain/index';
```

But when auto-importing WebStorm insists on importing the interfaces like this

```
import { Car } from '../shared/domain/car.domain';
import { Person } from '../shared/domain/person.domain';
```

Is there any way to have WebStorm to prefer to import from the index file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open **File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import** settings and enable the option **[Use directory import]**

*Note:* requires **WebStorm 2016.3** or higher

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. I was half-expecting that WebStorm did not support this. Glad I was wrong.

Comment: As of Webstorm 2017.2 this setting is migrated to *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Typescript (Imports tab)*