# Angular2 - WebStorm import my modules by index.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

**Scenario**

I'm currently working on an Angular2 app which is growing in complexity. To manage this, we're dividing the app into Angular modules.

**Problem**

When I use a TypeScript class from one module in another Angular module, WebStorm automatically references the complete file location. I get this every time I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key

```
// main.component.ts
import {class1} from "../otherModule/folder/class1";
import {class2} from "../otherModule/folder/class2";
```

Here's the directory structure, each folder contains an index barrel which references the folders within it.

```
mainModule/
-main.component.ts
-main.module.ts

otherModule/
-folder/
--index.ts
--class1.ts
--class2.ts
-index.ts
-other.module.ts
```

**Ideal solution**

Ideally I would like to have WebStorm automatically only reference the module name when I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. So that I can change the location of the class within the module without worrying about dependent references.

```
import {class1, class2} from "../otherModule";
```

This functionality seems to be possible, as it works with the Angular core features and other npm modules.

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `index.ts` inside of `otherModule`?

Comment: @Puigcerber, yes there is, also updated the question to include the directory structure

Comment: Can you then post your `otherModule/index.ts`?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40637423/1057218

Comment: @anstarovoyt That is the answer I was looking for,  thankyou both for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40637423/1057218

You need to open **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Typescript (Imports tab)** settings and enable the option **[Use directory import]**

*Note:* requires **WebStorm 2017.2** or higher

[image]